# Is Limit Order classified as Trading rather than Investing?

Tags: investing, trading, brokerage

I had a [question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/159040), and a [Scholar](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/12439/keshlam) has commented below.

[image: Scholar Comment]

> Sounds like you're trading rather than investing. Good luck; you're going to need it

So my questions are below( despite my very long and monetary successful personal investing history, I consider my self **student**),

1. Is entering a **LIMIT** order part of **trading** and **not investment** ?
2. Is trying to **save on interest** part of **trading** and not investment ?
3. Is only **Market** order **investment** and **everything else is trading** ?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to 'time' the market with precision. Many would consider this trading rather than investing.

Comment: Market order is just a type of an order. **Why** you're putting this order is what makes the difference.

Comment: Market order can be used by traders who are sitting all the time market is open logged on to their brokers. But Limit Orders will be used by people who  does not log on to he brokerage till price reaches the point that they like

Comment: A limit order is used to set a limit on how much you're willing to pay for a security or what price you're willing to sell at. Utilizing such an order does not make you a trader or an investor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others mentioned before, the order type (Market, Limit, whatever) is a technicality and has nothing to do with the very subjective question if your trades would be considered "active trading" vs "investing" or "speculative" vs "conservative".

I'd like to add that it very much always appears prudent to add a limit to any order. A market order, in contrast, signals your willingness to buy or sell **at any price no matter how bad**. This is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The term trading is not precisely defined. It is not a precise term. The way I think of it is that any time you place an order to buy or sell a security that is trading. As such, if you want to do investing you are going to do some trading also.

So buying LMT with a limit order (or a market order) is trading. If you are buying with the idea that you are going to keep it for a long time, then I would consider that investing.

Comment: Trading is the buying and selling of securities with the intent of profiting from short term price movements.